# R code to create a new variable based on existing variable

Tags: r, r-markdown

how would I write a R code if I wanted to create a variable based on existing variables in my datatset. For instance, I have the variables of gender and score. I want to create a new variable that contains only the scores of females.

Comment: Can you say what you've tried so far? http://www.simonqueenborough.info/R/basic/lessons/Subsetting_Vectors.html https://hughjonesd.github.io/subsetting.html

Answer (score 0):

Is this how u mean

```
female_scores <- total_scores %>%
                   filter(gender=='female')
```

Comment: Hi, I tried it, but it gave me an error message as the following:
Error in UseMethod("filter") : 
  no applicable method for 'filter' applied to an object of class "c('integer', 'numeric')"

Comment: can you show the code example, easier to decode the problem